# How to add a Symfony bundle in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, symfony

I am using netbeans to work with Symfony projects. But I wanted to try to use Eclipse. I added all the necessary plugins from the eclipse marketplace and I am able to create Symfony project with Eclipse.

The problem is when I want to add a bundle to the project... how do I do that with Eclipse, there is no New->Symfony Bundle for example, there is nothing

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible..

Prefezr netbeans plugin for Symfony... the command lines are integrated... You could do the same with Eclipse but you have to build each of them thru the external tool